# Can we Print using a Normal printer in IOS

Tags: ios5, ios4

I want to Know whether I can print a file through AIRPrint Printers only.

OR

I can print through a normal Printer connected to a Machine which can be connected through WIFI.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built in API to print to anything other than an AirPrint printer.

If you put in all the hard work of writing your own printer drivers (or porting someone else's), you could presumably print to a normal printer, but it ain't going to be simple.